# Detect Flash Player - Display Alternat Content

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I have been embedding flash swf files in HTML for years now, but I have never successfully detected the Flash Player version and displayed my alternate content successfully.
Maybe I'm missing something really simply that I'll never understand unless I ask someone, so here is my HTML code ( with URL edited ). There are only two files involved ( swf and HTML ) and they are at the same location on the server.

Note: This HTML was generated by SWFObject2

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js">
        swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "10.1.52", "expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body { background-color: #bbccff;}
    body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="200%" id="myFlashContent">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.mySite.com/redirect.swf">
            <param name="scale" value="noscale">
            <param name="salign" value="tl">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.mySite.com/redirect.swf" width="100%" height="200%">
                <param name="scale" value="noscale">
                <param name="salign" value="tl">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <table width="100%">
                                        <td align="center">
                                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="http://www.mySite.com/GetFlashHTMLMS.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                                    </a>
                                </td></table>
                                <br>
                                <table width="100%">
                                                <td align="center">
                                    <a href="http://www.opera.com/mobile">
                                    <img src="http://www.mySite.com/Opera.jpg" alt="Can't find Flash for Mobile?  Download Opera" />
                                    </a>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, me again, hanging around on a Friday night expecting someone to answer this question.

I would like to know what is wrong with my code but I just found a great javascript example of how to use javascript to detect flash version and do the redirects, thought I'd post it here.

Good code, thanks to the author.

Comment: www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/detection.htm